# Password reset resets every password

Tags: windows-7, passwords, virus, anti-virus

This morning, I logged onto my PC before heading to college, to check the status of the infamous GameSpy closure, and found that Windows wasn't accepting my password.

I then proceeded to boot a Windows RE (Recovery Environment) disk, and replaced `sethc.exe` with `cmd.exe`, to enable me to run the `net user` command so I could reset my password.

The password was reset successfully, but when I logged into Windows, I noticed that ***everything*** was asking for a username and password!
As in, my Google Drive asked me to sign in again, and my web host's 'web-disk' required me to enter my details again.
All my browser data in Google Chrome was also reset, including my cookies, history, and cache. I have not checked with other applications, except that Skype also told me 'Sorry, we don't recognise your details', meaning that I had to sign in again.

What's gone on?
I checked for suspicious activity, and scanned multiple times with different antivirus programs (namely Malwarebytes Premium, Trend Micro Internet Security, & Windows Defender), and none of them found anything.

**Edit:**
Just as I was writing this, I got a warning from Malwarebytes:

[image]

Could Skype have been infected with something that none of the antivirus programs are picking up?
Needless to say, I have changed my Windows Backup schedule to backup hourly, just in case something *does* go wrong.

Comment: I didn't think it was a virus at first but I highly doubt that skype has anything to do with the Moldova Parliament. You may want to take precautions against a possible virus threat. I find it interesting that none of your programs picked anything up when you scanned your system.  edit: You most likely got some sort of malware now that I'm thinking clearly. I didn't make the connection of you not being able to log into your computer *facepalm*

Comment: @slow_excellence Weird, I very carefully monitor my ports (too many DoS attacks, it comes with being a gameserver admin), and just checked that port `12364` is closed, which it is. I'll run some more checks on Skype.

Comment: This does come from Moldova and I would suspect malicious activity.